# How to get value of last updated row from a table?

Tags: mysql, trigger

I want to insert the last updated row into a new table using a trigger?

How to fetch that row if any of the column (value) from that table has been updated or changed?

I am using this code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER database.tbl1_AFTER_UPDATE 
    AFTER UPDATE ON tbl1 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO tbl2 (c1,c2,c3) 
    SELECT c1,c2,c3 
    from tbl1; 
END
```

But this is inserting all the rows from `tbl1` into `tbl2`. I want only the updated rows to be inserted into tbl2.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html:

> Within the trigger body, the OLD and NEW keywords enable you to access
>   columns in the rows affected by a trigger. OLD and NEW are MySQL
>   extensions to triggers; they are not case sensitive.

So if you want the new rows being inserted on another table, you should use the syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl2 (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (NEW.c1, NEW.c2, NEW.c3);
```